# FormsModule not loaded

Tags: angular

I have ran [Google's Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt1/stackblitz.html) several times.
Most of the time, it runs quite nice, at least until the list of heroes, where I arrived.

But one time, I got  NG8002: Can't bind to '[ngModel)' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

I compared with a copy that works, app.module.ts are identical, app.component.ts are identical, heroes.component.ts are identical.

Where do you think I should search for the error?

Compared the files with a copy that works. The files being identical, I expected the results to be identical. Just in case, I tried to launch `npm install` a new time, but with the same results.
The syntax where the error appears:
`<input [[ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />`

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be considered as obvious, but it was only when I read the syntax here in the forum (which I had not published yet when Abhay Gusain answered). I should have compared the versions of the html files with WinMerge.

Instead of
`<input [[ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />`
I have to type
`<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />`

I have to release the AltGr key between two times I depress the same key, to obtain either [ or (. And it seems my movements were not coordinated enough.

Several times for the previous versions I typed nbModel instead of ngModel, but then I saw the error.

Comment: By the way, it has happened that FormsModule is not recognized, and I have to comment some declarations of things I do not use, and then it works.